Any issues with EDB Postgres, plpython3u, Psycopg on Apple Silicon?
I currently have an old Intel i7 based iMac. I plan to upgrade to the M4 Mac Mini (Apple silicon).
I am running Postgres and use plPython (plpython3u) internally for procedures and triggers. Externally I use psycopg to access the DB from Python. I use an ODBC driver (Actual Technologies) to access the DB from MS Excel.
Does anyone know if there are any issues running the above tech stack on Apple Silicon ? I'd hate to spend all that money and end up with a huge pile of trouble.
Update: I got the M4 Mac. I will update with any issues I find.

The EDB PostgreSQL install had issues.



Can you rent one fror a week?
